# filter file by rows with python

Tags: python, filter

I have a file with several columns:

```
1.000       2.0072      1.000       3.5368      1.000       3.7748
2.000       2.0890      2.000       3.5867      2.000       3.7302
3.000       2.0784      3.000       3.3057      3.000       3.6899
```

I need to filter it in such a way that I only select the rows that meet a specific condition for each column, for example just select the rows for which:

```
C1 < 1
C2 > 2
C3 == 3
```

In total there are 5 columns and I need to filter only the rows that meet the three conditions of the example. I had raised something like that but I filtered all the data at the time:

```
k = open ("test.txt", "r")

lines = k.readlines ()
     for line in lines:
        conv_int = int (lines):
         if lines> 1:
             print (conv_int)
```

Comment: Can you add your initial try? So people can see what went wrong instead of solving for you. It's customary on SO to show your efforts.

Comment: You could consider using the pandas module and load your file as a csv (with a space separator). You would then only need to apply filters corresponding to your needs.

Comment: Hello, I tried to do it with pandas but I have not succeeded, I changed my data to a .csv file and did the following:

Answer (score 0):

Let's get some things straight:

- I don't see an interpretation for which any of the lines in your example would pass the three filters.
- trying to cast the lines to `int` wouldn't work the way you wrote it, and is not necessarily a good idea anyway, due to the rounding effect.

But by adding some guess work, you can bend the following to your needs, hopefully getting the principles and fixing things up to you more general case:

```
k = open ("test.txt", "r")
lines = k.readlines()
for line in lines:
    nums_list = [float(x) for x in line.strip().split(' ') if x != '']
    if nums_list[0] < 1 and nums_list[1] > 2 and nums_list[2] == 3:
        print(line)
```

Again, this won't print anything with your example, but the idea should be clear. If not then ask in the comments and I'll clarify if needed.
Good luck!

Comment: Did my suggestion not work? If so where did it fail?